# I need explaination python list and range function

Tags: python

I am new to Python. This code generates a list
`[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]`
can someone kindly explain how it works?

```py
positions = [(r, c) for r in range(3) for c in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 8):

That's what's known as a list comprehension (if you want to do further research). The statement `positions = [(r, c) for r in range(3) for c in range(3)]` can be read as:

> Create list `position` where each element `(r, c)` is populated for `r` values `0..2` inclusive and, *within* each of those `r` values, `c` values `0..2` inclusive.

It is therefore *functionally* the same as:

```py
positions = []
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(3):
        positions.append((r, c))
```